# Deserialize varbinary in file

Tags: c#, serialization, varbinary

I'm working on this:
I have some file and I insert their properties in a database, including corresponding varbinary. I do it this way:
I convert it in mimedata, then I serialize them in a binaryformatter obtainining a byte array.
So I insert the result in a db with sql.

So, the process that you could use to deserialize is to reverse, but, my question is, there is a faster way to do it?

Comment: It's very hard to know without more details than "I insert their properties" - there are all kinds of serialization formats available, but we don't know which ones will be suitable for you without more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example:

```
Car car = new Car("BMW");

BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bFormatter.Serialize(ms, car);
System.Data.Linq.Binary carBinary 
    = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(ms.ToArray());

TestDB db = new TestDB(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
db.InsertObjectSerialize(carBinary);

ISingleResult<GetObjectSerializeResult> result = db.GetObjectSerialize(1);
System.Data.Linq.Binary carBinaryFromDB
    = result.Single().Object;
ms = new MemoryStream(carBinaryFromDB.ToArray());

Car carFromDB = (Car)bFormatter.Deserialize(ms);
```

> Taken from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1507343.aspx/1).

Comment: Thank you @CarlosLanderas! I think that it is the best way!

Comment: I did as soon as I could ;)